# Website detects selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

I was creating an automation login to enter [this](https://www.eurobic.pt/) site using selenium an everything was normal until yesterday(only appear a icon in the tab and a blank browser page)...i can load all other sites, but not this through selenium..using this:

```
 from selenium import webdriver

 url="https://www.eurobic.pt/"
 driver=webdriver.Firefox()
 driver.get(url)
```

don't work. I have read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver) and maybe this is the reason, they can detect the webdriver or simply put me on blacklist.How can i load the site again through selenium?

Comment: Can you please check once whether the site is accessible through normal browser .. I mean without the automation ...as I have tried to open it but couldn't able to do it ...

Comment: yes, i can enter through normal browser, in both firefox and chrome..thats why i don't understand, that was the first hypotesis, that site was down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code with *Mozilla Nightly* build of **61.0a1 (2018-04-21) (64-bit)** and pretty much able to access `https://www.eurobic.pt/` without any issues. You can use the use the following code block :

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files\Firefox Nightly\firefox.exe')
url="https://www.eurobic.pt/"
driver=webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
```

Browser Client Snapshot :

[image: MozillaNightly]

Comment: why the binary? finally after i spend yesterday working on the problem and today i fix it...but don't no how :D between pc repairs, packages reinstaled...anyway you got my vote for constante help.ty man

Comment: @Sátiro I had to use the `FirefoxBinary()` as the _firefox.exe_ doesn't resides in the usual location as this is the _Mozilla Nightly_ build of **61.0a1 (2018-04-21) (64-bit)**

Comment: hi, can you tell me what is wrong with my javascript post? it has downvotes and i don't have any clue why, ty

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to invoke the url using java in chrome.

Below is the code and I have attached the snapshot of the result.[Url invoked successfully in chrome browser in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMQQl.png) [52944ms.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce0sZ.png)

```
public class Eurobic {
    WebDriver driver;
    @Test
    public void invoke_Url() {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Shubham Kumar\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.eurobic.pt/");
    }
}
```